# What sort of initialization does initializer_list allow for in this constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I'm using a GUI library for a textbook I'm going through. One of the constructors used for a 'Lines' object in it has the following code.

```
struct Lines : Shape {  // independent lines
    Lines() {}
    Lines(initializer_list<Point> lst) : Shape{lst} { if (lst.size() % 2) error("odd number of points for Lines"); }

    void draw_lines() const;
    void add(Point p1, Point p2) { Shape::add(p1); Shape::add(p2); }
};
```

I've tried the following initialization, but it show the E0289 error, stating

> `no instance of constructor "Graph_lib::Lines::Lines" matches the argument list`

```
Lines li{ {Point{100,100},Point{200,200}},{Point{150,150},Point{250,250}}};
```

I want to know how the `initializer_list` is supposed to work in this context and how am I supposed to use it when constructing an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're actually passing **two `initializer_list`s**. This construction isn't defined, hence the compile error.

```
Lines li{ {Point{100,100},Point{200,200}} , {Point{150,150},Point{250,250}} };
//        ^-----------------------------^                                       first        
//                                          ^-----------------------------^     second
```

The following changes should compile:

1. Use nested initializer-lists in the **constructor**:

   ```
   Lines(initializer_list<initializer_list<Point>> lst)
   ```
2. *OR* Add a second parameter in the **constructor**, accepting another initializer-list:

   ```
   Lines(initializer_list<Point> lst, initializer_list<Point> lst2)
   ```
3. *OR* Combine the two initializer-lists in the **call** into a single one.

   ```
   Lines li{ { Point{100,100}, Point{200,200}, Point{150,150}, Point{250,250} } };
   //        ^----------------------------------------------------------------^
   //        one initializer-list
   ```

> I want to know how the `initializer_list` is supposed to work in this context and how I am supposed to use it when constructing an object.

Given that the class definition was provided by the textbook, you're probably looking for #3 above, where the `Point`s are grouped into **one** `initializer-list`.

I'm guessing the GUI side of it is probably implemented to ***connect subsequent points forming connected lines***, rather than accepting *pairs of points forming separate lines*.